# Custom table names in Papertrail don't work with save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I am trying to use a custom tablename (`papertrail_versions`) in my PaperTrail configuration. I have the settings as described in the documentation:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail class_name: "::PapertrailVersion"
end

#papertrail_version.rb
class PapertrailVersion < PaperTrail::Version
    self.table_name = :papertrail_versions
    self.sequence_name = :papertrail_versions_id_seq
end
```

When I look for `User.last.versions`, the query formed looks for the table `papertrail_versions`, but when I save a "dirty" User instance, I instead get an error:

```
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "versions" does not exist
LINE 5:         WHERE a.attrelid = '"versions"'::regclass
                                    ^
:       SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
            pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"versions"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You may have found a bug. If you can reproduce the error using the [bug report template](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/doc/bug_report_template.rb), please open an issue on github. Thanks!